# Compiling Firefox from source with custom defines?

Tags: firefox

I've been doing some tinkering with the Firefox source code, and I'd like to be able to compile it with some custom defines.

For example, the Firefox source code has some `ifdef` blocks like this, where `EXAMPLE` is one of many constants.

```
#ifdef EXAMPLE
    // code here
#endif
```

What I'd like to do is enable some of these constants, presumable by configuring my [`.mozconfig` file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Configuring_Build_Options) to set them somehow.

I haven't found any documentation on how to do this, but based on some examples, I thought maybe adding this might do the trick.

```
mk_add_options EXAMPLE=1
```

But it didn't work, and neither does this (`DEFINES: command not found`):

```
DEFINES += -DEXAMPLE
```

It must be possible somehow though, as presumably Firefox developers are using this feature.

How can I set some custom defines for the Firefox build scripts?